# Why Function is not using the parameters values even the values are recieving?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```js
const currencyFormatter =( value,format, currency, minimumFractionDigit) => {
      console.log(minimumFractionDigit)
      const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(format || 'en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: currency || 'USD',
        minimumFractionDigits:minimumFractionDigit ? minimumFractionDigit :2,
      });
      return isFinite(value) ? formatter.format(value) : '';
    };
    
    console.log( currencyFormatter(Math.round(1234.89),undefined,undefined,0)) ;
```

So the issue I'm facing is that function is receiving the value 0 for the `minimumFractionDigit` but the function always returns a value with two decimal points. When I replace `minimumFractionDigits` with 0 it returns the desired output. What could be the problem here?
I want to return a value without decimal points from this function.

Comment: Notice that when `minimumFractionDigit` is zero, this expression results in 2, which is correct: `minimumFractionDigit ? minimumFractionDigit : 2`

Comment: `0` is a falsy value // so it goes to else in ternary ... `0 ? 0 : 2`  gives `2`

Comment: And this is why you should always use `===` and `!==` if you're not dealing with actual `true` or `false`. And you'll almost certainly want a little more code here, because even though a value of 0 should work, a value of -1 probably shouldn't. So you almost certainly want a `typeof` check (so you know it's a number) _and_ a `value >= 0` (so you know you're only dealing with legal values)

Comment: @KcH explains it well. now I know what went wrong. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Change your code like this

Set default value of minimumFractionDigit = 2

`The problem was, in javascript if value === 0 then it identified as false`

```js
const currencyFormatter = (value, format, currency, minimumFractionDigit = 2) => {
  console.log(minimumFractionDigit);
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(format || "en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: currency || "USD",
    minimumFractionDigits: minimumFractionDigit,
  });
  return isFinite(value) ? formatter.format(value) : "";
};

console.log(currencyFormatter(Math.round(1234.89), undefined, undefined, 0));
```

#### Or there is another way

```js
const currencyFormatter = (value, format, currency, minimumFractionDigit) => {
  console.log(minimumFractionDigit);
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(format || "en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: currency || "USD",
    minimumFractionDigits: minimumFractionDigit !== undefined ? minimumFractionDigit: 2,
  });
  return isFinite(value) ? formatter.format(value) : "";
};

console.log(currencyFormatter(Math.round(1234.89), undefined, undefined, 0));
```

Comment: You're always welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're using the ternary operator to evaluate `minimumFractionDigit`. It evaluates the `minimumFractionDigit` and if it's falsy, it will use the number 2.

0 evaluates as a falsy value.

Change it to this:

```js
minimumFractionDigits: minimumFractionDigit ?? 2
```

Comment: Or you could do `minimumFractionDigit ?? 2` using the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: I accepted an edit from Yone which included this. Thanks